# Select a random record from a Cartesian join grouped by one field

Tags: sql-server

Assuming a random dataset with an intentional Cartesian join, is it possible to extract a *unique* record for each username?

For example, my dataset (#t2):

```
UserName     City           State      Zip
bradley      Eagle Lake     TX         77434
bradley      Hudsonville    MI         49426
bradley      Egan           LA         70531
will756      Twin Rocks     PA         15960
will756      Palm           PA         18070
will756      Thornton       KY         41855
```

This was created with a Cartesian join.  Now I want to select one record for bradley and one record for will756, and I don't care which record it is.

How would one do this?

For completeness sake, here is the SQL I wrote to get me where I am:

```
select top 10 percent row_number() OVER (ORDER BY tmpZipCodes.Place,tmpZipCodes.StateCode,tmpZipCodes.ZipCode) n,tmpZipCodes.Place as UserCity, tmpZipCodes.StateCode as UserState, tmpZipCodes.ZipCode as UserZip 
into #t1
from [tmpDropDowns]
inner join tmpZipCodes on tmpZipCodes.uStateCode = tmpdropdowns.StoredValue
where tmpdropdowns.DDLName = 'ddlState' and CountryCode = 'US'
order by newid()


select member_login.username as UserName, #t1.UserCity, #t1.UserState, #t1.UserZip 
into #t2
from member_login, #t1
```

Comment: if you're using sql 2008+ you can apply row_number to each row and partition by Username.. then just select all rows with row_number of 1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: Given the info above, how would I write that?

Comment: Actually, given that this is a Cartesian I'm thinking I'll end up with every username using the same City/State/Zip

Comment: You've already used row_number() in the first query.   Why can't you adapt the solution in Jamie's comment?